# Get Thumbprint from Application keyCredential

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am fetching my organization's applications using the MS Graph API, and I am attempting to read the thumbprints of the certificates attached to each. It returns a `byte[]` but I can't seem to find the right encoding to convert to `string`.

The graph API returns a list of `Application` objects, which have a `KeyCredentials` enumerable, and finally a `CustomKeyIdentifier`, which should be the thumbprint. See this [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/keycredential?view=graph-rest-1.0) page for more details on `KeyCredentials`.

The code I have tried is

```cs
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(credential.CustomKeyIdentifier);
```

This returns gibberish characters, presumably because the encoding is incorrect, but I have tried every other encoding option available in `Text.Encoding` to no avail. How can I convert the `CustomKeyIdentifier` to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a Base64 string so

```
System.Convert.ToBase64String(credential.CustomKeyIdentifier);
```

Or if you want the Hex version which is generally what people want when looking at the thumbprint it would be

```
BitConverter.ToString(credential.CustomKeyIdentifier).Replace("-","");
```

Comment: Fantastic, it didn't occur to me that the thumbprint was actually a hex string. Thanks!